# Kendo DropDownList requestEnd push value undefined

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I have a DropDownList initialize via the data- attributes. I need to add an item to the list but the code I'm using displays the value as 'undefined' after I push the new option.

Here is my element using the data- attributes (works fine):

```
 <select id="#people_list"
     name="person_id"
     class="form-control"
     data-role="dropdownlist"
     data-source="datasource_people"
     data-option-label="Select A Name"
     data-auto-bind="true"
     data-text-field="name"
     data-value-Field="name"
     data-ignore-case="true"
     data-filter="startswith"
     >
     </select>
```

Here is my datasource params (works fine):

```
datasource_people = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        type: "json",
        serverFiltering: true,
        transport: {
            read: {
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/restful/people/'
            }
        },
        filter: {
            field: "status",
            operator: "eq",
            value: 1
        },
        schema: {
            data: function(response) {
                return response.data.people;
            },
            model: {
                id: "person_id",
                fields: {
                    person_id: {type: "number"},
                    name: { type: "string"}
                }
            },
            errors: "error",
            total: function(response) {
                return response.data.total;
            }
        }
    });
```

Then Later (doesn't work - adds new item as 'undefined'):

```
$("#people_list").kendoDropDownList({
    dataTextField: "text",
    dataValueField: "value",
    dataSource: {
        datasource_people,
        requestEnd: function (e) {
            e.response.push({text: "John", value: "John"});
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: It may be that dataTextField and dataValueField are incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looked through some of the docs for other methods and this worked perfect.

```
$("#people_list").getKendoDropDownList().dataSource.insert({
    person_id: "John",
    name: "John"
})
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should define datasource's request end event like this, instead of putting it inside initiation code of your DropDownList

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  transport: {
    read: {
      url: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/products",
      dataType: "jsonp"
    }
  },
  requestEnd: function(e) {
    var response = e.response;
    var type = e.type;
  }
});
```